# What is this spawn egg item, and how do I remove it?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I was working on a project in Minecraft Bedrock Edition, when I came across this spawn egg in the creative menu. I was curious about what it spawned, but when I tried to use it, it just spawned an odd cube thing (see image below).

I am now unable to remove the spawned block, despite being in creative mode. I also unintentionally spawned several of them by misclicking. It's right in the middle of my build, and quite the inconvenience.

**EDIT:** The world I was playing in was one downloaded from the marketplace and I initially didn't believe that it had any additional resource or behavior packs but after double checking I've realized that it does, the world was called Minecraft; The Mountain (I believe it's based off of some book? Idk it just looked pretty so I wanted to build in it) and it came with a resource pack and a behavior pack, both of which share the same name

[image]

What is this spawn egg item, and how do I remove it?

Comment: Do you have any resource/behavior packs installed on your world? If so, please name them in your post for our reference. The item is likely to be part of an addon that has an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's a entity, perhaps a /kill @ e command would work with this situation. In my experience this command is able to kill or despawn any mobs and/or entities in the loaded area.

Comment: However this may be a more tricky situation if you have mobs that you're attached to on that world (for example; pets, or villagers with good trades), as when you do /kill @ e it'll kill them too.

Comment: I think you could kill by ID which appears to be `blockception:time_-detector`.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right I believe there is indeed a way to only kill a specific entity type. However I can't remember the specific text needed for the command at this moment unfortunately.

Comment: I used the /kill @ e solution as the specific id command didn't work(luckily I was just building in creative and didn't really have any mobs I was particularly attached to) and that removed them! Thank you all for your help!

Comment: @EmmeKay glad it helped! Don't forget to mark this post as the answer to your question using the checkmark!